# Error al pasar dato de un campo select multiple a la BD LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Bueno obtengo los datos de materia de una tabla de mi BD y los mando al un select  Al querer guardar el dato del select a la base de datos me sale el error que el campo materias no tiene valor[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al checar los datos que se mandan por post resulta que si se envio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui mis codigos

vista

```
<label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
    Materia 
      <select class="custom-select " id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref " id="materias" name="materias" >

            <option  selected >Elige...</option>
            @foreach ($materias as $id => $name)
                <option value="{{ $name }}">{{$name}}
                {!! $errors->first('name', '<span class=error>:message</span>') !!}
                </option>
            @endforeach
      </select>
</label>
```

controlador

```
public function create()
{
    //
    $materias = Materia::pluck('nombre','id');
    return view('libros.create',compact('materias'));

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  App\Http\Requests\CreateLibroRequest;  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(CreateLibroRequest $request)
{
    //
    //dd($request->all());
     $libro = Libro::create( $request->all() );

     //$libro->materias()->attach($request->materias);
    return redirect()->route('libros.index');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira el siguiente ejemplo.

```
<select name="channel_id" id="channel_id" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="">Choose a option...</option>
  @foreach($channels as $channel)
    <option value="{{ $channel->id }}">{{ $channel->name }}</option> 
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: saludos y bienvenido @Jonathan soy Alfredo, te comento que deberías por favor añadir una explicación a tu código, es decir por que resuelve el fallo del OP para que se eleve la calidad de tu publicación saludos y que bueno verte por aquí

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Gracias por la sugerencia, soy nuevo por aquí y espero aportar lo poco o mucho que conozco de Laravel :D Saludos.